# How to get the row index of a UITableView by dragging a UIImageView on it

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, drag-and-drop, uiimageview

I am developing an app that requires me to drag a colored box that is a UIImageView on top of a row of a UITableView. When I release the colored box on a specific row, I want to change the color of that row to the color of the box. 
Currently I am able to drag and drop the box but I'm facing problem in getting the row index of the row on which I release touch. 
The image attached depicts what I want to do. I have dragged the red box on the blue row, and I want to change the color of the row from blue to red. But I cant figure out a way to get the row index on which I drop the box.[image: The Image depicts what I want to achieve.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get tableView cell by getting indexPath at rootPoint, like this.

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.tableView];

CGPoint cellPoint= [sender.superview convertPoint:touchPoint toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:cellPoint];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Can you please help in finding the root view point. I am currently using the method touchesEnded.

Comment: see the edited answer... I think we can get touch point fro touch object in view.

Comment: I'm getting your point but I cannot quite understand what is rootViewPoint and how to get it.

Comment: it should be cellPoint

Comment: I passed the cellPoint as parameter but indexPath returned is nil, I think it is because the point is out of bounds of the viwe but I don't know the reason why.

Comment: Concept will work if you get points in tableView, so try to debug and see what the cellPoint value, is it in tableView bounds or not...?

Comment: CGPoint touchPoint1 = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.myTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint1];

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
int abc = indexPath.row;
This is how i worked it out. Thanks alot for your help. Its working fine now :)